# Vulnerability for Apache zookeeper common/default node accessible without ACL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

How to perform Apache zookeeper common/default nodes accessible without ACL on Kafka server?

How to perform vulnerability

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. We're not going to help you hack a system, assuming it were possible